# subversion's caret notation (repository-relative path) causes error

Tags: svn

Switching from Subversion 1.5 to 1.8, I would like to become comfortable with the ^ notation, but I can't get it working. For example,

```
svn list ^
```

causes the error message

```
svn: warning: W155010: The node '/cygdrive/c/playground/dvp/Kernel/^' was not found.
svn: E200009: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist
```

while using the URL form,

```
svn list svn://cmtcd040192/trunk/dvp
```

works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the final slash:

```
svn list ^/
```

works!